# dataType 'application/json' vs. 'json'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$.ajax - dataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype)

I am using jQuery 1.8.2, and for some reason `'application/json'` does not work, but `'json'`  works as `dataType` to a standard `jquery` `ajax` call. Is this a glitch? A version related difference? or is there an established difference between the two?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '<c:url value="/url.htm" >',
        //dataType : "application/json", <-- does not work
        dataType: 'json' // <-- works
        success : function(data) {
            // do something          
        },
        error : function(data) {
            // do something else
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Also, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: `dataType` has a limited set of (space separated) options, and it's not the mime type. See [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 11):

`dataType` takes json, it means the request expects a `json` response.

`contentType` takes `application/json`, it means the request is sending `json` data

You can send as well as expect json in a request e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    contentType : "application/json", 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({some: 'data'}),
    success : function(data) {
        // do something          
    },
    error : function(data) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

here you're sending json and expecting xml

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    contentType : "application/json", 
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: JSON.stringify({xmlfile: 'file.xml'}),
    success : function(data) {
        // do something          
    },
    error : function(data) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

and here you're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded`(jQuery automatically sets this for you), and expect json back

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: '1'},
    success : function(data) {
        // do something          
    },
    error : function(data) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

contentType sets the `ContentType` HTTP request header, telling the server that the body of this request is of the given type.
dataType sets the `Accept` header to tell the server that this is the type of response we want e.g.

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

but regardless of what type of response the server sends jQuery will still attempt to parse it as whatever type you set in the dataType field.

Comment: I think it would be cool to expand on this and explain what $.ajax is doing behind the scenes to let the server know what we expect and what we are sending.

Answer (score 1):

"application/json" is the correct mime type for json.  The jquery `dataType` field, however, is expecting one of the following strings:

```
"xml"
"html"
"script"
"json"
"jsonp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the json documentation, the correct dataType is "json".

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here are the options supported:

- xml
- html
- script
- json
- jsonp
- text