# javascript cannot send '+' character with ajax parameter

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters

I need to pass the '+' character with ajax parameter to my controller.

Ajax Call with parameter contain '+' charactor.

```
var subsNumbers = '+94'
var url = 'getList?subsNums='+subsNumbers;

$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (saveResponse) {
....
}
});
```

In my controller(Spring controller class),

```
String deviceNumbers = request.getParameter("subsNums");
logger.debug("deviceNumbers-->{}", deviceNumbers);
```

the '+' character has been replaced with space.
Actual result is

```
deviceNumbers--> 94
```

Expected is

```
deviceNumbers-->+94
```

Comment: your ajax dataType is `JSON` but your sending a string right? and for your question I guess it can be solved by **Url Encode @Client** and **Url Decode @Server**.

Comment: @Yashhy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735869/datatype-application-json-vs-json

Comment: @Musa thanks that was well explained!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your url is not properly encoded, use `encodeURIComponent`

```
var url = 'getList?subsNums='+encodeURIComponent(subsNumbers);
```

Comment: to explain why: the + character in a URL is by convention a substitute for the illegal space character, so if your URL contains + symbols, the receiver MUST interpret them as "these are really spaces".