# Can't pass Javascript array to PHP via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've been tearing my hair out at such a simple problem. I have the following JS array:

```
    var orderDetailsArray = new Array();
    orderDetailsArray[0] = 'test 1';
    orderDetailsArray[1] = 'test 2';
    orderDetailsArray[2] = 'test 3';
    orderDetailsArray[3] = 'test 4';
```

Then I have the following Ajax code to send this array to a PHP file

```
    $.ajax({  
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://testdomain.com/file.php',
       data: JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray),
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
       }
    });
```

In my PHP file I have the following

```
   $orderDetailsArray   = json_decode($_POST['orderDetailsArray']);                     
   echo $orderDetailsArray[0];
```

But for some reason `alert(data)` always just returns blank. I have no idea why this doesn't return the correct values.

Any help would be really great.

Thanks

Comment: So do you want to send JSON or receive url encoded form data?

Answer (score 4):

You did not name your array in the client side before sending it, therefore the *whole* of `$_POST` is this array, and `$_POST['orderDetailsArray']` is undefined.

You must name it client-side:

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "POST",
   url: 'http://testdomain.com/file.php',
   data: {
       orderDetailsArray: JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray)
   },
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Um I'm still getting an empty response alert with this

Answer (score 1):

```
data: { orderDetailsArray: JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post data is **not** a key value pair, so you cant access in via key in php.

Either use the php input stream:

```
$orderDetailsArray   = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

**OR** set a key in your ajax:

```
data: { orderDetailsArray: JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray)}
```

Comment: Um I'm still getting an empty response alert with this

Comment: For the second option your content type is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `array` like this and then can directly pass it `ajax`. (No need to `stringify`)

```
var orderDetailsArray = {};
orderDetailsArray[0] = 'test 1';
orderDetailsArray[1] = 'test 2';
orderDetailsArray[2] = 'test 3';
orderDetailsArray[3] = 'test 4';

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://testdomain.com/file.php',
    data: {'order_details':orderDetailsArray},
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I doubt that without stringify that it would would work. Post data is usually serialized when using ajax.

Comment: @Peter Its worked for me and thats why i have posted it. Using like this, we dont need convert it to array in PHP. We can directly access it as array in PHP. So  $_POST['order_details'] is an array.

Comment: And i think its the easiest way. Otherwise we need to convert it into a string in the front end and then in the back end need to convert the string to array and then process:)

Comment: by your code above, you created an object not an array, Which would work normally without stringify. But for an array, you have to either serialize or stringify it.

Answer (score 0):

without dataType

```
data: {orderDetailsArray :orderDetailsArray},
```

with dataType

```
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify({orderDetailsArray:orderDetailsArray}),
```

Comment: If I use dataType, do I still need to include contentType: "application/json", ?

Comment: I think no need if you use dataType: "json",

Comment: @punithasubramaniv you're mixing up contentType with dataType, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735869/datatype-application-json-vs-json

Comment: yeah thats okay, I dint say strictly use only one. I said not necessary, If you use dataType. For the coding procedure you want to use all somthing like this contentType : "application/json", dataType: 'json'... But am using single dataType without using contentType also I can get the output. Thats why I suggested. Sorry If i confused.

Answer (score 0):

well you cannot pass the value directly, you need to assign it to a "key" like this

`data: {'arr':JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray)},`

and access the same at php side like this

`$orderDetailsArray   = json_decode($_POST['arr']);`

**Reference:**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the data submitted. On the server side there's no data specified for 
`$_POST['orderDetailsArray']`

Change your ajax to:

```
$.ajax({  
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://testdomain.com/file.php',
       data: 'orderDetailsArray='+JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray),
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try change the data:
    data: JSON.stringify(orderDetailsArray)

//by

```
data: {orderDetailsArrayData:orderDetailsArray}
```

or

```
data: JSON.stringify({orderDetailsArrayData:orderDetailsArray})
```

// in php

```
$orderDetailsArray   = $_POST['orderDetailsArrayData'];                     
echo $orderDetailsArrayData[0];

or 

$orderDetailsArray   = json_decode($_POST['orderDetailsArrayData']); 
echo $orderDetailsArrayData[0];
```