# Convert jQuery .ajax with dataType: json to plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I can use jQuery for fast drafting / prototyping but I can not YET implement it on our production servers.

I need assistance with getting the plain javascript version of the following to work.  In the plain javascript version *submit.php* is not receiving the json data.

### Original jQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      data: json,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(json){
        alert('success');
      }
  });
```

### Plain javascript:

```
  var xmlhttp;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","submit.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  xmlhttp.send(json);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {                 
      alert('success');
    }
  }
```

Comment: So it works using `jQuery` but submit.php is not recognizing data sent via plain javascript?

Comment: Try `xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(json));`

Comment: That's because you're not sending JSON data and neither is the original $.ajax.

Comment: How is `json` defined? jQuery does some magic based on what kind of data is passed in.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735869/datatype-application-json-vs-json/

Comment: @Musa if `json` is a proper json string, he is sending json data.

Comment: @KevinB fair enough, but I doubt it

Comment: @Kevin B & @KJ Price: The exact same data that is working with the jQuery version is not with the plain ol' javascript version.  All I have changed is the ajax call.  My assumption is jQuery is either doing something to the `data: json` or `dataType: "json"` isn' the same as `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`  But I don't know which.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that i need to see how you defined it..

Comment: if `json` is a string, jquery will send it as such, if it is an object, jquery will send them as POST params and not JSON. Unfortunately that is further complicated by people calling objects json.

Comment: This is how the json is defined: `var json = new Object();   json['element1'] = "value1";   json['element2'] = "value2";   json['element3'] = "value3";` this is what it looks like with JSON.stringify(json) `{"element1":"value1","element2":"value2","element3":"value3"}`

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer!!  Hope others find it useful.

jQuery adds default headers (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

jQuery converts the data (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
"It is converted to a query string, if not already a string."
```

jQuery then sends the request as a regular POST query string.

I found the needed snippet to convert from json to a POST query string in Plain JavaScript here: https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/issues/199

Here is the updated plain JavaScript code:

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","submit.php",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    alert('success');
  }
}

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

var pairs = [];
for (var key in json) {
  pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(json[key]));
}

var data = pairs.join("&");

xmlhttp.send(data);
```