# sending an ajax GET with a javascript response format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I am trying to do the following

```
$("select.languages").on("change", function(){
        var lang = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $.get(url: "/search",
                data: {"lang": lang},
            dataType: 'script');
    });
```

so every time a language is selected I would call `/search` with the language and by other SO answers to make dataType be "script"

but this doesn't quite work. What does work is

```
$.get( "/search.js",{"lang": lang} )
```

yet this pollutes the url since the format is very explicit and doing using this method requires me to add extra pointless code

can I implicitly set the response format?

Comment: if I add curlys I get a weird url which results in `http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/search",
  data: {"lang": lang},
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

The [get shorthand method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) does not accept the parameters as an object like this.

Comment: can you explain what you mean?

Comment: **does not accept** are you sure? on your link you have provided just scroll down to last one.

Comment: cache busting solved with  `$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});` seems to work until it breaks

Comment: @Jai, it doesn't accept an object as the only parameter like the $.ajax function does, it accepts an object as the second parameter for that parameter data

Comment: @slicedpan `data: {"lang": lang}` you have to takeout the `data:` from this part.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a syntax error - I would try this:

```
   $("select.languages").on("change", function(){
        var lang = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search",
            data: {"lang": lang}
        });
    });
```

Since you're trying to send a JS request, you probably won't even need the `dataType` property, as Ajax expects it by default:
[$.ajax - dataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype)