# How to store data from a local javascript file into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is probably pretty easy but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I have a local javascript file with JSON data (data.js) that I would like to call from another js file (build.js) where I will name the array.  How would you do this?

**data.js**

```
[
  {"name": "bob"},
  {"name": "sally"},
  {"name": "jane"}
]
```

**build.js**  --> I've tried storing the data in a string and even that is not working...

```
var namesArray;

function build(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.js',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            namesArray = String(data); // this part doesn't work!!
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    build();
});
```

Ultimately what I want to achieve is to be able to call namesArray[0].name and be able to output "bob"... but I definitely do not want to name the array from within data.js.  Help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `namesArray = data;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify to jQuery the type of the data and then use it directly.

```
function build(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.js',
        type: 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            namesArray = data;
            console.log(namesArray[0].name); // bob
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yep. this works. nice job!  why is dataType needed to achieve this?

Comment: This post answer your question: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype)