# How to run "success" function in MVC4 Jquery Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a simple MVC4 application with C# and jQuery. In this application, when the user presses a button with the id of `SaveCheckboxChanges` I send two arrays of data to the server. Then the server processes the data and saves it on the DB.

While this is happening, I want the pressed button to change. 
Currently, when the user clicks the button, the buttons text changes to `'Saving changes'` which is good, but then it never changes back.

This happens because the `success` function that I send in the Ajax request is never being called, only the `error` function is called even though no errors happen and I get the `OK` answer.

Controller that receives the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCheckBoxes(int[] requiresSetupArray, int[] disabledArray)
{
    //Do operations with the requiresSetupArray and disabledArray Arrays
    DB.SaveChanges();
    return Content("OK");
}
```

At first i assumed this was happening because the `UpdateCheckBoxes` method was `void` and was not returning anything. But now that I changed it to what is above, only the `error` function is called.

Javascript code being executed:

```
$("#SaveCheckboxChanges").click(function (event) {
        var button = $("#SaveCheckboxChanges");
        if (!button.hasClass("disabled")) {

            button.attr('value', 'Saving changes');

            var requiresSetupArray = [1, 2];
            var disabledArray = [3, 4];

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Material/UpdateCheckBoxes',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({ requiresSetupArray: requiresSetupArray, disabledArray: disabledArray }),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success " +  data);
                    button.attr('value', 'Save Checkbox Changes');
                    button.addClass('disabled');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

How do I fix this?
Am I forced to return something in the controller's method for the `success` function to run? If so what should I run?

Comment: "OK" is not JSON. Check out explanation in what I though should be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype, but really duplicate of some "how to return JSON in ASP.Net MVC".

Comment: What??? I do not undertstand the link between this and datatypes, can you exlpain?

Comment: I do not want to return anything. All I want is to run the *success* method.

Comment: That exactly what happened with the post - you expecting "answer" but random person just provided stupid comment - so complete failure... If you look at your code it expects "json" as result, but your controller returns random text - so the only option for ajax call is to fail.

Comment: Can you make sure you always print JSON code?  Don't send 'OK', but (for example) send {"message": "OK"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect your method to return anything - don't require JSON as result:

```
$.ajax({


       url: '/Material/UpdateCheckBoxes',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //  dataType: 'json', - remove this line.
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ requiresSetupArray: requiresSetupArray, disabledArray: disabledArray }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success " +  data);
            button.attr('value', 'Save Checkbox Changes');
            button.addClass('disabled');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Alright! Does this mean that my controller's method can be void after all? Or do I **always** have to return something? If yes, what should I return in this case?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix `void` should be fine - try.