# How to send javascript dictionary to controller method in MVC4

Tags: c#, ajax, json, model-view-controller, controller

I have a js file that has to send a dictionary object to the server. My javascript part looks like that:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: myData
        });
```

where **myData** is something like

```
this myData["favouritePet"] = "dog", myData["favouriteBook"] = "What?"
```

In the controller I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ActionName ( Dictionary<string, string> jsonFormattedData)
{


    return null;
}
```

but when I debug it the parameter gets a null value every time. I tried to make the argument of type string but it is the same. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Side note: Your data isn't in `JSON` format, but an `array`.

Comment: I have declared it as {} in the beginning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype

Answer (score 1):

You are just passing JavaScript object, so you can use **JSON.stringify** and make the Model as Action parameter.

MVC Model Binder will convert it to your model.

[image]

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public string FavouritePet { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteBook { get; set; }
}

// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyDataModel myData)
{
    return View();
}

<button id="btnSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var myData = new Object();
        myData.favouritePet = "dog";
        myData.favouriteBook = "What?";

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (){}
        });
    });
</script>
```