# XML Post with PHP form works, jQuery .ajax does not

Tags: php, jquery

I have a very simple PHP form which posts XML data to a URL, which then responds with more XML. Here it is:

```
form action="[...]" method="POST">

        <textarea name="xml" rows="30" cols="100">
            <RRequest version = '2.13'>
                <Request>
                    <Command>update</Command>
                    <Pd>
                        <RID>1</RID>
                        <ExtID>111111111</ExtID>
                    </Pd>
                </Request>
            </RRequest>

        </textarea>
        <br>
        <input value="Submit Request" type="submit">

    </form>
```

This works beautifully. I am attempting to implement the same thing, but using jQuery. Here is that code:

```
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#submit").click(function(){

                var xml_data = $("#xml").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "[...]", 
                    data: xml_data,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "text",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#xml").val("");
                        $("#xml").val(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert("it no works");
                    }
                });

            });

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

        <textarea id="xml" rows="30" cols="100">
            <RRequest version = '2.13'>
                <Request>
                    <Command>update</Command>
                    <Pd>
                        <RID>1</RID>
                        <ExtID>111111111</ExtID>
                    </Pd>
                </Request>
            </RRequest>

        </textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" />
```

This, however, does not work. It does contact the server, but the server returns a bad request message, which makes me think the data being sent is not correct. The two textareas containing the XML are identical. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using jQuery 2.1.3.

Comment: Is it posting to a remote server?

Comment: @Jon Yes it is. The files I'm working on are kept on my local machine, but they are posting to an absolute url (https).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype . I think dataType should be XML..

Comment: I don't believe you can post from AJAX to a different server. XSS I believe is the name to look for regarding that.

Comment: *sings* What does the Fiddler say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
  var xml_data = $("#xml").val();
```

with

```
  var xml_data = {xml: $("#xml").val() };
```

UPD:
these parameters should be removed from your .ajax() request:

```
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "text",
```

Comment: Thank the old gods and the new. Well done, friend. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious, do you see any reason this would work in Safari, but not Firefox?

Comment: @user1647550, yes, this code will work in any browser

Comment: That's what I thought too. It works flawlessly in Safari, but hits the error handler immediately in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: show us the error, please. probably, you need to put xml param into quotes, i.e. { "xml": ... }

Comment: When I attempt it, It hits this part of my code: error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){alert("it no works");} so I receive that alert. I tried putting the xml parameter in quotes, but that did not work either.

Comment: check textStatus and errorThrown values to get more error details

Comment: also... remove these params from your code:  contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "text",

Comment: The textStatus type was error, and the errorThrown was empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74883/discussion-between-user1647550-and-softwarrior).