# what is the difference between application/json and json only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, types

I have seen  return type json , application/json while working with ajax. I have tried both and found the same result. Please anyone let me know the difference between these two.

```
 datatype: 'json'
 datatype: 'application/json'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.ajax - dataType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype)

Comment: You should read about `MIME types`, check out this [list](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery's `datatype` argument on the `$.ajax` method accepts either the name of a format (like `json` or `xml`) which jQuery knows how to parse, or a MIME type (like `application/json`), which jQuery can map back to a parseable type. In this case, jQuery is mapping `application/json` to `json` for you, because it's a common format.

The `datatype` argument is not what MIME type you expect from the server, but *how jquery should parse the response*.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `jQuery.ajax` says:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
>
> [...]
>
> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.