# Why need to include dataType to JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the next code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     data: {language: language},
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        result.forEach(function(item) {
           var option = $("");
           option.text(item);
           option.val(item);
           node.append(option);
        });
        if (self.value.country) {
            $("#countrySelect").val(self.value.country);
        }
    }
});
```

why at first case (when I refresh page or visit it at first time) it returns json and at the next case (postback) it returns string
Then I add

```
dataType: "json"
```

And now it returns only json.
Why without adding it not worked correctly?
1) with dataType [image]

2) without dataType (first load) [image]
3) without dataType (postback)[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.ajax - dataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722750/ajax-datatype)

Comment: you didn't add the proper json header to your route

Comment: @madalinivascu Explain please what you mean

Comment: your route returns plain text not json so jquery doesn't know you have json, by adding the dataType you tell jquery that the string is a json object

Comment: for your route to return json you need to append the json header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @madalinivascu Ok, got it, but why at first case (when I refresh page or visit it at first time it returns json) and at the next case (postback) it returns string

Comment: i can't tell without a closer look at your xhr request and backend route

Comment: @madalinivascu I updated!

Comment: The fix is as discussed (specify explicitly) - the cause has nothing to do with how you are calling the action, but rather what the action is returning.  You've (conveniently?) left this off your images / code.  There could be a subtle difference in the return value from your MVC action which means jquery doesn't recognise it as json.

Answer (score 1):

Because without specifying `dataType`, it takes a guess at the type. By specifying it to JSON, it will expect a JSON data response. You also can't specify multiple data types - if you need different data types returned, you have to leave it set to the default value.

Comment: but why at first case (when I refresh page or visit it at first time it returns json) and at the next case (postback) it returns string