# How to read JSON and get data

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to read JSON to take name and status?

I tried everything and [0] - [1] and without it

```
[
    {
        "status": "OK"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name test test"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name test"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test name"
    }
]
```

ajax

```
   $.ajax({
     url:'url',
     method: 'get',
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(response){
        if (response.status === "200") {
           $.each(response, function(i, data) {
            alert(data.name);
           });
        } else {
          alert('error status');
        }
     }
  });
```

Comment: Are you talking about the HTTP status, or the status in the first object of the response?

Comment: first object and id, name

Comment: a) [$.ajax - dataType](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2722750/215552) You must use `dataType: 'json'` if you want it to parse your data as JSON. b) if you're asking how to get data from that arrray, [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/215552)

Comment: The JSON data is an array of objects, and you are accessing it as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ajax `dataType` should be "json":

```
dataType: "json"
```

jQuery will automatically parse that returned JSON into a JS object.

And then you can iterate over the objects in the returned array and log the values of the properties you need.

```js
const response=[{status:"OK"},{id:"1",name:"name test test"},{id:"1",name:"name test"},{id:"1",name:"test name"}];

$.each(response, function(i, obj) {
  if (obj.status) console.log(obj.status);
  if (obj.name) console.log(obj.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if (obj.name) console.log(obj.name); not working .. return nothing

Comment: But if you run the snippet it clearly is working. That's your data. What else is your code doing?

Comment: I replace  console.log with alert and does not work

Comment: Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case because you have data that isn't a match you can go with this:

I am using an if statement to check if there is status then print it else its the field with in your case name and id so it prints that. I am also using success so it only gets to success when the api returns a status of 200.

[For Each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       data.forEach(function(elem){
          if(elem.status){
             console.log(elem.status)
          }else {
              console.log(elem.name)
          }
       })
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    }
});
```

and if status is only on the first element in the array then use the index of the array to print it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       data.forEach(function(elem, index){
          if(index < 1){
             console.log(elem.status)
          }else {
              console.log(elem.name)
          }
       })
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should explain what you've changed.

Comment: I'm testing what you offered me.. not working

Comment: does your data return json or text? console.log(typeof data)

Comment: this console.log(data); - return [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] .... this console.log(elem.status) - return - OK (this work) ... this return  console.log(elem.name) -  undefined

Comment: dataType: "json",

Comment: can you give me the api you are trying to call, so i can test myself

Comment: @Schnecke - PHP $response[] = array('status' => 'OK');
       $response[] = array(
         "id" => $row['userID'],
         "name" => $row['name'],
       ); return json_encode($response); PHP and header is set Content-Type: application/json

Comment: I cant run the code you sent, so i guess just in the first console.log do this console.log(typeof data) to see if you get back a string or array or object

Comment: i use array before i do it json

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use jQuery and read a json, you need to change the dataType property to "json". You [can read more about it here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Otherwise, you also can do it without jQuery and it could be more simple today

```
//...
try { 
   const response= await fetch('yoururl');
   const data = await response.json();
}catch(error){
    console.error(error);
}
```

[You can also read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)